# Scroll view doesn't resize when the content of child view changes

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I have a `WebView` inside the `ScrollView`.

The content of `WebView` dyanamically changes when it displays different html page.

I have the following issue:

For example I have `A.html`, and `B.html`. The content of `B.html` is larger than `A.html`, so the page is longer.

When `WebView` load `B.html`, the ScrollView stretches its size to enable itself scroll for B.html, then if I go back to `A.html`, ScrollView doesn't resize itself. (The scroll area is exceed the content of `A.html`)

[image]

What I want to have, is dynamic change the scroll area of scroll view to fit the webview's content.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

That's not good idea to place WebView inside of ScrollView. WebView is smart enough to show scrollbars by itself.

Comment: What if we have content above the WebView that we want to scroll as well?  Is there a way to cause the ScrollView to re-evaluate?

Comment: I wonder why this answer is accepted, the question was "How?" rather than "Is it good idea?"

Comment: But he's right (in most cases). If author of question decides to mark answer, he/she probably knows what doing.
I wonder why it' bad...

Answer (score 5):

Try using `android:fillViewport` in scroll view..!!

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Answer (score 1):

After Orientation screen will resize, it works but bad in performance, not a very good solution

```
setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE );
setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR );
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```xml
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    
    <WebView
       android:id="@+id/webView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -7):

Don't put a `WebView` inside of a `ScrollView`.