# Android WebView adding strange empty space at the bottom

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to add more empty space to a loaded `WebView` using `JavaScript`.

I load data using `loadDataWithBaseUrl()` from a `String` resource. 
Then, after measuring some content, I need to make `WebView` bigger, say for 100 pixels.
So I call javascript function using `loadDataWithBaseUrl()`:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:addHeight()");
```

`Javascript` function is defined in the original HTML:

```
function addHeight() { " +
    var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
    elemDiv.style.cssText = 'height:100px;'; 
    document.body.appendChild(elemDiv); 
}
```

After this, `WebView` resizes itself to fit the new content. However, resulting height is not originalSize + 100px, but bigger.
I don't know where's the problem. I can't determine the target size, because it depends on the size of the appended `div` and it will be always different.

Has anybody tried this? Are you familiar with this behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Shrink WebView size dynamically according to its content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546416/how-to-shrink-webview-size-dynamically-according-to-its-content)

Comment: By "resulting height", do you mean the height of WebView view element (on the Android side), or the page dimensions, as reported by `window.innerHeight` or `window.outerHeight` in your JavaScript code?

Comment: this is not a clear question , please show your javascript addHeight() code.

Answer (score 2):

I [found the next solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25187094/2413972). There used JS callback. I hope this helps you. This change in size should work better than dynamic.

```
    private void setupWebView() {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyApp");
}
@JavascriptInterface
public void resize(final float height) {
    MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, (int) (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
        }
    });
}
```

And of see paragraph 4 [of this list](http://vision-apps.blogspot.ru/2012/08/android-webview-tips-tricks.html). Good luck!

Comment: Using Android 5.1.1, nothing seems to happen - setting LayoutParams doesn't change the WebView at all.